# Aks Role assignement in namespace

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created a role and role binding for my aks cluster to restrict my users that are part of a group to only view the secrets in my namespace but they are not allowed to edit the secrets so i have added the list action to the verb in role. But after applying my role and role binding still my users in group are able to view and edit the secrets in my namespace i am attaching the role and role binding for reference

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: listOnlysecretBinding
  namespace: devtest
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: listOnlysecret
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    namespace: devtest
    name: "9ijk008-330k-900g-800a-7567678ccaa"
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: listOnlysecret
  namespace: devtest
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    verbs: ["list"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `RoleBinding.subjects` is incorrect:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: listOnlysecretBinding
  namespace: devtest
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: listOnlysecret
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: Group
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    name: listOnlysecret-group
```

Comment: so in subjects instead of namespace there should be apiGroup is that the mistake i made?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide the apiGroup which the reference role exists. You would use the namespace field to select a `ServiceAccount` kind, not `Group`. 

See here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/rest_api/rbac_apis/rolebinding-rbac-authorization-k8s-io-v1.html#subjects-2

> Namespace of the referenced object. If the object kind is non-namespace, such as "User" or "Group", and this value is not empty the Authorizer should report an error.

Comment: Had made this change bt still it's not working and members are abel to edit the secrets

Comment: Please verify your work first by using `kubectl auth can-i list secrets --as user --as-group listOnlysecret-group -n devtest`. It's your quickest way to a resolution.

Comment: if the user has cluster level admin privelage for read writing and editing through entire namespace will it override the kubernets role applied to the namepace also do we need to delete the .kube from local machine before checking the policies in place?